# is it possible to access subversion from ironpython?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, ironpython, pysvn

Python has a subversion bindings called 'pysvn' that can be used to manipulate subversion repository. Does something similar exists for IronPython?

My test platform in Windows 7 64-bit with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I may be ignorant, but can't you just use pysvn?

Comment: I maybe be not very familiar with python 'binding' concept, but i don't know how to use a binding that installs for python 2.6 to be used in IronPython. Simply doing "import pysvn" from within Visual Studio raises "no such package" exception.

Comment: I believe pysvn uses C++ internally so, if this is true, you can't use it without porting it to C++/CLI or something like that first I believe. http://pysvn.tigris.org/

Comment: you should add that to your question.  Also, if you put an @ symbol in front of someones name, it SO will notify them of a new message (I would have come back sooner then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe .net based solution will be better: [sharpsvn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/)

Comment: This may help! Maybe you can look at my other question at http://j.mp/aTNhLr - i can't figure right now how to correctly add reference to third-party sharpsvn .net .dll to IronPython project :)

Answer (score 2):

if @gruszczy solution doesn't work you could look into [ironclad](http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/) as well

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can import `pysvn` in `IronPython`, but you have to add python `site-packages` directory to `IRONPYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Adding python site-packages folder to IRONPYTHONPATH just results in Visual Studio 2010 crashing on startup :(

Comment: Try solution provided by Lucas, I am not `IronPython` specialist unfortunately :-(